# Abort java webapp on startup

Tags: java, websphere, web-applications

My webapp is part of a larger EAR that is deployed into a websphere server. The server hosts number of other apps on the same virtual server. My webapp has some initialisation/health checks in a servletContextListener->contextInitialized method. I want to make the webapp unavailable if initialisation/health checks fail. What is a realiable way of doing this? Will throwing a RuntimeException from within contextInitialized  suffice? Is the rest of the EAR still expected to be available? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend throwing a `RuntimeException` from `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized`.

Servlet 2.3 wasn't very clear on this, but Servlet 2.4 added the following detail:

> Some exceptions do not occur under the
>   call stack of another component in the
>   application. An example of this is a
>   … ServletContextListener that
>   throws an unhandled exception during a
>   notification of servlet context
>   initialization…. In this case,
>   the Developer has no opportunity to
>   handle the exception. The container
>   **may** respond to all subsequent requests
>   to the Web application with an HTTP
>   status code 500 to indicate an
>   application error.

Since it says that the servlet engine "may" disable access to application, you might find a server that does something else. However, Tomcat and WebLogic both disable the application, and the only other reasonable thing I can think of would be to ignore the exception. I can't see a container that did that being very popular—so you'd better test it in WebSphere yourself.

Comment: Glassfish 3.0.1 refuses to deploy a web application, if ServletContextListener.contextInitialized throws a RuntimeException. However, if the application has already been deployed, and a RuntimeException is thrown when the server is restarted, GF 3.0.1 refuses to start at all (which makes it impossible to undeploy using the supplied tools). In this case we opted to set a ServletContext attribute in the listener, and output error message in a filter.

Comment: Websphere stil doesn't =( In case of `RuntimeException` or `Error` during `#contextInitialized`, it just prints warning message and continue running, though returning HTTP 500 for any web request.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a RuntimeException will probably make only that servlet unavailable.  A safer way might be to implement something like a Spring interceptor that will forward to an error page or something if the checks didn't pan out.  That way, you don't need to prevent the app from loading, but can handle it more gracefully at run time.