# How to abort Startup procedure on init-Exceptions

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have a WebApplication on Websphere 8.5.5.8, one (more or less empty) EAR Project which contains my WAR Project.

In my main Servlet, which is loaded on startup, i do some checks, if everything is alright.
If its not, I'm throwing a `javax.servlet.ServletException`.

**My expectation** is, that Websphere would recognize that there is a Problem and abort the startup of my application so its not usable at all.

**What actually happens** is, Websphere just logs that Exception away with only Waring level, the Exception is even in another File, not in the Log itself:

```
[06.04.16 07:42:27:229 CEST] 0000004c FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC-Vorfall an C:\IBM\WAS8.5\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_bb44715_16.04.06_07.42.27.2056702894000999712166.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletInstance.init 259 erstellt.
```

Then my Application is started anyways so its available to use with a Browser. People of course then start using it and recognize later, that that there is a Problem. After digging in Log files, it comes out that the startup failed.

**Question**: 
What can i do to make Websphere abort the Startup Process?
Is there maybe a Special kind of Exception i could throw? 
I tried

- `javax.servlet.ServletException`
- `javax.servlet.UnavailableException`
- `java.lang.Error`

I found [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=98644673-0380-4ed7-9d41-3bb6356bf6a4) in the IBM Forums, which indicates, that my expected behavior would violate the JEE Spec, which wouldn't make much sense for me.

I tried a `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272747/5072526), one Plus is, that i'll get a error Message in the log, but the Application still starts.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337927/5072526) I tried the Startup Beans. The solution posted there is not working for me, those proprietary startup beans are [not allowed in a WAR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/cejb_ejbinwar.html), and they're are also [Deprecated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/asyncbns/tasks/tasb_confstb.html?lang=en). I only have a EAR Project, since Websphere/RAD is forcing me to use one in my local environment. On Test/Production Systems, only the WAR is used.

If i use the startup beans defined by EJB 3.1:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MyStartupBean {
    public boolean start() {
        System.out.println("MyStartupBean.start()");
        return false;
    }
    public void stop(){
        System.out.println("MyStartupBean.stop()");
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("MyStartupBean.postConstruct()");
    }
}
```

The `start()` method doesn't get called, i only see the `postConstruct()` message in my log. Throwing an Exception in `postConstruct()` wont abort the startup process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Java EE application start on WebSphere on exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337421/prevent-java-ee-application-start-on-websphere-on-exception)

Answer (score 0):

So far, i only came up with an Workaround (inspired by the comment of Jason Faust in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1337927/5072526):

Have a static flag, and if the initialization has completed correctly, set it to true.
Use a Filter to check that flag and output an Error if its false, so at least the Application dosen't seem usable when the Startup failed:

```
public class HealthCheckFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(AppBridge.isStartupFinished()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.setCharacterEncoding(AppConstants.ENCODING);
            httpResponse.setContentType("text/plain");
            httpResponse.setStatus(500);
            PrintWriter out = httpResponse.getWriter();
            out.write("Startup failed");
        }
    }
    /* Methods init(FilterConfig filterConfig) and destroy() ommitted*/
}
```