# Stop deployment when Exception occurs in ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic

I have following web.xml configuration where exception is thrown at `com.mkyong.context.ContextSecond` in contextInitialized() method. In that case deployment does not stop and app.war keep servicing. How I can stop deployment when exception occurs?

**Using weblogic 12c**

Archetype Created Web Application

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mkyong.context.ContextFirst</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mkyong.context.ContextSecond</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**ContextFirst .java**

```
package com.mkyong.context;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ContextFirst implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ContextFirst:contextDestroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println("ContextFirst:contextInitialized");

    }

}
```

**ContextSecond .java**

```
package com.mkyong.context;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ContextSecond implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ContextSecond:contextDestroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println("ContextSecond:contextInitialized");
        throw new RuntimeException();

    }

}
```

Log:

```
<Nov 19, 2014 1:52:36 PM EET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149124> <Failures were detected while initiating remove task for application "webservices". Error is: "[Deployer:149001]No a
pplication named "webservices" exists for operation "undeploy".">
ContextFirst:contextInitialized
ContextSecond:contextInitialized
<Nov 19, 2014 1:53:05 PM EET> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.mkyong.context.ContextSecond failed: java.lang.RuntimeException.
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at com.mkyong.context.ContextSecond.contextInitialized(ContextSecond.java:18)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
```

Comment: If you have any servlet in your app it will not work. Can you try the servlet? But it seems that you are using web services, and web services are working?

Comment: I have an other listener (ContextLoaderListener for Springframwork) and their order is given above. When ContextSecond throws and exceptions, this does not effect the first ContextListener(Spring) and webservices or rest services provided by springframwork keep servicing.

Comment: What happens if your force call a `destroy()` rather than `throw new RuntimeException();`

Comment: which class belongs to destroy() method? How can I can invoke it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a ServletContextListener stop the Java EE application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657319/how-can-i-make-a-servletcontextlistener-stop-the-java-ee-application)