# How to prevent spring context loading on exception in ServletContextListener?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-listeners, spring-ioc

I boostrap spring context using `ContextLoaderListener`. 
Before this in **web.xml** I have my custom listener which pefrorms some checks. If those checks fail i do not want Spring context to be started.

How can i prevent Spring context loading if i had an Exception in another listener?

I would put some attribute in ServletContext, but i do not know how it can affect on loading of spring ctx.

Here is the very similar question: [Stop deployment when Exception occurs in ServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012166/stop-deployment-when-exception-occurs-in-servletcontextlistener)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did to solve that:

In my listener where i perform some checks, if something wrong happens, i set attribute to servlet context

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("checkFailed", true);
}
```

Then i extended Spring's `ContextLoaderListener` and overrided `contextInitialized` like this:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    if (event.getServletContext().getAttribute("checkFailed") != null) {
        return;
    }
    super.contextInitialized(event);
}
```